# Snapshot for custom DevExpress grid

Tags: testcomplete

I have a custom DevExpress Grid overrided with custom GridView. How could I use table snapshots in TestComplete to support this control.
For custom TreeList I found the steps:

You can adjust TestComplete so that it handles a custom control in the same way as the corresponding “standard” control by using the Object Mapping feature. This feature sets a correspondence between control types and their possible class names. To specify that TestComplete should treat a specific control as one of the supported controls:
•   Right-click your project in the Project Explorer panel and select Edit | Properties from the context menu. This will open the Project Properties Page.
•   Select Object Mapping.
•   In the list of control types, choose the type corresponding to your custom control.
•   Press Add Class Name and enter the control’s class name.
-- or --
Click Add From Screen and capture the control using the subsequent Add New Object Class dialog.
The class names are case-insensitive and can contain wildcards (* and ?).
•   Select File | Save from TestComplete’s main menu to save an object mapping template for the current project.
Note:   TestComplete also provides scripting access to a number of child controls of supported third-party controls. Generally, you can work with a child control in the same way you work with its parent. For more information, see Working With Custom Child Controls.

You can not only add an object mapping template for a custom control in the current project, but for all new projects created with TestComplete. This is done in through the Object Mapping Options of the Default Project Properties dialog. In this case all new projects will already be “familiar” with the custom control.

and they work

Comment: TestComplete supports ASP.NET, .NET Windows Forms and VCL components from Developer Express. Which exactly framework does your application use?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you are working with a .NET Windows Forms applications that uses a grid based on the control from Developer Express, the base grid control is, most probably, **XtraGrid**. TestComplete has advanced support for this grid control (see the [Working With Developer Express XtraGrid - Overview](http://support.smartbear.com/support/viewarticle/14581/) topic) and you can map your descendant grid to this supported control using the [Object Mapping](http://support.smartbear.com/support/viewarticle/11156/) feature indeed.

To do this, you need to open the current project' properties editor (***Tools | Current Project Properties***), select the **Object Mapping** options group and find a record for the base **XtraGrid** control as the **Developer Express Controls | XtraGrid** item. Add the full name of your custom grid's class to the list. This name is stored in the [ClrFullClassName](http://support.smartbear.com/support/viewarticle/11667/) property of the grid object. You can see this property in the [Object Browser](http://support.smartbear.com/support/viewarticle/11024/) panel.